# How to skip wpf validation when the model is initialized?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to create a wpf error validation for a textbox.  Looks pretty simple but after days and trying many methods I'm still trying to figure out the proper way to do this.

Here is my code (this is not my real code, just an example):

## The textbox

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Model.Name , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" 
        Style="{StaticResource NameTextBoxStyle}" />
```

## The style

```
<Style x:Uid="Style_81" x:Key="NameTextBoxStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
        <Trigger.Setters>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=              (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger.Setters>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

## The class

```
Public Class SomeClass
{
    public bool IsNameMandatory { get; set; }

    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (IsNameMandatory && String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                throw new Exception("Name can not be empty.");
            }
            if (value.Length > 12)
            {
                throw new Exception("name can not be longer than 12 charectors");
            }

            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem**: The error validation is working but when the model is "initialized" and set a blank value to "Name" an exception is raised with a messagebox instead of the red rectangle with the tooltip. I **don't** want to display the exception in a messagebox.

**My needs**: I need to validate the error only on **LostFocus** of the textbox and **on demand**

Answer (score 2):

Here is how WPF validation is properly done using [Binding.ValidationRules Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validationrules%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

In your View:

```
xmlns:tools="clr-namespace:SomeAppNameSpace.Tools"

<TextBox Style="{StaticResource SomeStyle}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="SomeProperty" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus" >
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <tools:SomeValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

ValidationRule class located in your tools (or equivalent of) namespace:

```
public class SomeValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, 
      CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var userText = value as string;
        return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userText) ? 
            new ValidationResult(false, "Value must be provided.") : 
            new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

So, this simple `ValidationRule` checks the textbox on `LostFocus` and if the textbox is left empty it returns a validation error message...

Last piece of the puzzle is that your "SomeStyle" which is the style for the textbox above must have `Validation.ErrorTemplate` defined... something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="SomeStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate >
      <!-- Your Error Template here. Typically a border with 
           red background and a textbox with light colored text...  -->
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Tanks Dean...  Works perfectly! I have two other question : 1- Is there a simple way to force the tooltip to be displayed (at least when the error is triggered...without having to point the mouse over the textbox) ?  2- My someValidationRule class is directly in the window codebehind...in a typical wpf project where the validation rules are defined?

Comment: I have a more important question : 3- in the SomeValidationRule class example Is it possible to validate the Result of "SomeProperty" and having acces to the another properties of my model "SomeOtherProperty" ?  (The result of the validation is based on many properties of the model)

Comment: 1. Yes, you can use a DataTrigger within your ControlTemplate for Validation.ErrorTemplate with IsKeyboardFocused property. Too much XAML to paste in here. 2. Not sure about what would be typical but I keep all the validation classes in a single cs file in my Tools subfolder... 3. Yes, it's possible, you have to define these other properties as resources in your XAML and register them as DependencyProperty... get the class form github: https://github.com/DenisVuyka/WPG/blob/master/Main/WpfPropertyGrid/DataResource.cs

Comment: Thanks again!  I saw that DateResource class before, now I know that this is the way to go.   BTW Im using your WPF since the very begining...I'm glad to get your help ;o)

Comment: The only thing i'm still working on is to have the tooltip displayed for 5 seconds when the error is triggered (without the need to move the mouse over the control for the first time)   Will proably create my own error template but only if this is my only choice.  any idea for showing the tooltip on lostfocus or somehting else?  Thanks

Comment: Try DataTrigger.EnterActions and within that place a StoryBoard with 5 second duration...